# css show validation message above the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given that I have the following html bit:

```css
form p label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: green;
}

#myField.error {
  content: 'validation error occurred';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div id="myField">
  <p class="required">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="error" maxlength="10" value="" title="Username" required />
  </p>
</div>
</form>
```

how can I show the validation error message above the input field, floating to the right? I don't want to modify the html code manually. However, adding some span tag using jquery or js is fine. All said, a css solution is preferred.

Comment: What are you doing to ensure that the field is valid in the first place?

Comment: @Okomikeruko that part is already done using some javascript code. Now i am facing an input field which has a class of error.

Answer (score -1):

I made small change to your html, moved the error class from input to p element. And in css used ::before CSS pseudo element (and took the liberty to add a red border for input & red color for error message)

```css
form p label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: green;
}

#myField .error::before {
  content: 'validation error occurred';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  color: red;
}

#myField .error input {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div id="myField">
  <p class="required error">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="" maxlength="10" value="" title="Username" required />
  </p>
</div>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle link for this code](https://jsfiddle.net/karthikeyan_shanmugavadivelan/djL0ztm5/)

Comment: unfortunately i can't add the error class one up, it is part of the input. is it possible to do the same without moving the error upwards?

Comment: This is not the way to show error message validation